# Unable to find element with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

the title says it all, I can't find an element with selenium in python.

This is my code:

```
    import time
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    
    s = Service("C:\Program Files (x86)\Chromedriver.exe")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
    
    driver.get("https://soundcloud.com/signin")
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    
    cookies = driver.find_element(By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler")
    if cookies.is_displayed():
        cookies.click()
        ...
    
    time.sleep(5)
    
    signup = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "Your email address or profile URL")
    signup.send_keys("test")
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the error in detail?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing that exception

```
Unable to find element
```

cause the desired element is in iframe. So first switch to iframe and then interact with the desired web elements. Also `name` is `email` not `Your email address or profile URL`

**Code :**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@src,'https://secure.soundcloud.com/web-auth')]"))
time.sleep(5)
signup = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "email")
signup.send_keys("test")
```

Also if this works, try to remove `time.sleep(5)` and use `WebDriverWait` instead

Comment: Furthur I test this with `time.sleep(1)` not 5, and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

As already explained, the element `signup` is in an `iframe`. You can also use indexing to switch to `iframe`.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://soundcloud.com/signin")
driver.find_element_by_id("onetrust-accept-btn-handler").click()
driver.switch_to.frame(0) # Required singup element is in the 1st iframe.
driver.find_element_by_id("sign_in_up_email").send_keys("Sample Text")
```

Comment: Index switching is not recommend in automation, cause the moment they have a new iframe, index won't work. having said that it is last resort.